# NSString stringWithFormat : how to pass only not empty strings?

Tags: objective-c

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@ \n%@",
 self.message1,self.message2,self.message3];
```

There's a way to pass only message1 ..2 ..3 only if not == "" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to suggest an alternative and more compact solution:

```
[[@[self.message1, self.message2, self.message3]
    filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]]
            componentsJoinedByString:@" \n"];
```

So unlike Mundi's solution that:

1. creates an array of all strings that may be used;
2. creates a predicate that differentiates between strings you want and strings you don't want;
3. creates a second array by filtering the first using the predicate;
4. asks for all items in the second array to be glued together with a string and a newline in between.

There are obviously more steps in there so it'll cost a bit more but for most purposes you really don't need to care about that nickel and dime stuff.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass `@""`, nothing will be displayed anyway, so that would not be the problem. So I am  assuming you also do not want the line breaks if the string is empty.

```
NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString string];
if (self.message1 && self.message1.length) {
   [s appendFormat:@"%@ \n", self.message1];
}
if (self.message2 && self.message2.length) {
   [s appendFormat:@"%@ \n", self.message2];
}

if (self.message3 && self.message3.length) {
   [s appendFormat:@"%@ \n", self.message3];
}
```